# How to Implement Search Functionality In flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been stuck trying implement the search functionality in flutter,

So I have this search icon button

```
       IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showSearch(
              context: context,
              delegate: CustomSearchDelegate(),
            );
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        )
```

OnPressed It uses the CustomSearchDelegate Class Below

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  AllBackEnds _allBackEnds = AllBackEnds();

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (query.isEmpty) {
              close(context, null);
            } else {
              query = '';
            }
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear)),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) => IconButton(
        icon: BackButtonIcon(),
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        },
      );

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List>(
        future: _allBackEnds.getUsers(),
        builder: (context, adsSnapshot) {
          if (!adsSnapshot.hasData) {
            return CustProgIndicator();
          } else {
            List _dat = adsSnapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _dat.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                Map<String, dynamic> _userAds = _dat[index];

                return CustomWid(data: _userAds);
              },
            );
          }
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List>(
        future: _allBackEnds.getUsers(),
        builder: (context, adsSnapshot) {
          if (!adsSnapshot.hasData) {
            return CustProgIndicator();
          } else {
            List _dat = adsSnapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _dat.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                Map<String, dynamic> _userAds = _dat[index];
                return CustomWid(data: _userAds);
              },
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

The `_allBackEnds.getUsers()` is returning an array of objects like this

```
[{s_n: 1, name: Drizzy}, {s_n: 2, name: Omah Lay,}];
```

So I want to search using the name

So the buildSuggesion Widget & buildResults Widget are just displaying a list of custom users card, without the actual search feature.

How can I implement the suggestions & search functionality with my code shown?

Answer (score 0):

the proper way to solve this issue is : first of all you have to make model to store that data,after making model use textfield and enter sometext, in onchange method of textfield you can check that the list of model data is containing this data you have entered in text field like

```dart
void searchContact(String textfieldresult,modelList) async {
 searchedList.clear();
 var value = modelList.where((element) =>
 element.name!.toLowerCase().contains(textfieldresult.toLowerCase()) ||
    element.name!.toUpperCase().contains(textfieldresult.toUpperCase()));
searchedList.addAll(value);
  return searchedList ;
}
```

this method will return searched values